# Excel VBA - Filter on ComboBox does not recognise first value

Tags: excel, filter, combobox, userform, vba

I have a userform set up which contains a ComboBox.   The ComboBox is populated with values which are pulled from a range of cells which have been defined in the Name Manager (range of A1:A5 stored in a separate sheet.)   The default caption for ComboBox is "Select Office"

On the ComboBox_Change() Sub I have the following code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets("wpdata").UsedRange
    .AutoFilter
    If ComboBox1.ListIndex > 0 Then .AutoFilter 5, ComboBox1.Value
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This works perfectly with options 2, 3, 4 and 5.

However,  when the first option is selected it does not filter at all and the filter remains on the previously selected item.   I have also tried to select option 1 first and it still doesn't filter.  I have tried re-ordering the ComboBox values but this doesn't have any effect,  the first option is still not recognised.

Does any one have any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If ComboBox1.ListIndex > -1 Then ...........
```

Comment: Ah Ha!   Thank you.   Sometimes you need a fresh set of eyes.